Async version of Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration()
This is similiar to Timed caching in Vertx, but the value I want to cache is obtained asynchronously.
In synchronous code I'd do:
Supplier<String> supplier = Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(this::provideTokenInternal, 50, TimeUnit.MINUTES)

String provideTokenInternal() { .. }

String provideToken() {
  return supplier.get()
}

How would I achieve a similar result, but using async programming:
WhatINeed<String> supplier = WhatINeed.memoizeWithExpiration(this::provideTokenInternal, 50, TimeUnit.MINUTES)

Future<String> provideTokenInternal() { .. }

Future<String> provideToken() {
  return supplier.get()
}


Maybe I could use the Guava supplier directly, but I'm not sure if it makes sense to cache Future objects?
E.g. people report issues with reusing the Future objects.
Also the Guava implementation uses locking, I expect a verte.x native solution would do without locks.
I guess I could try Caffeine but it seems like an overkill if all I want to cache is a single access token.

I often see lazy memoization used when the author instead wanted a periodic reload. The former incurs caller observed latency because the item expires periodically so the callers wait and in low activity all of the memoizers have timed out so the initial request is slow. A periodic scheduled task that swaps the datum allows the load to be asynchronous to hide the latency, but does useless work in off hours. What is your intent and ideal behavior?

Caffeine would exactly what you want. There's an how-to demonstrating integration with Vert.x. Otherwise, you could use a Vert.x AsyncMap, which has a put method with ttl param.

@BenManes periodic update would be more optimal, but also more complicated to handle errors because of the indirection, so my approach was to use memoization until somebody complains about the latency

@tsegismont I'm aware of Caffeine, but as stated in my question it feels to much to pull in to cache a single value. I'm not sure how put with ttl helps? I want to avoid the expensive operation of getting the token, what I would need would be something like computeIfAbsent with ttl, but I don't see any method like that in AsyncMap

computeIfAbsent can be emulated with get + put, that's what I meant

As I understand I need to add synchronization there to make it atomic then. I  mean I don't feel like using AsyncMap is helping much

In the end I went with the comment suggestion to use a periodic update task.
This turned out to be the easier route mostly because there is a ready solution in https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-auth/blob/e57448c145676d6d152fcb07a1bbf7daded22142/vertx-auth-oauth2/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/auth/oauth2/impl/OAuth2AuthProviderImpl.java#L115-L129
  public Future<Void> jWKSet() {
    return api.jwkSet()
      .compose(json -> {
        // enforce a lock to ensure state isn't corrupted
        synchronized (OAuth2AuthProviderImpl.this) {
          if (updateTimerId != -1) {
            // cancel any running timer to avoid multiple updates
            // it is not important if the timer isn't active anymore


            // this could happen if both the user triggers the update and
            // there's a timer already in progress
            vertx.cancelTimer(updateTimerId);
            ((VertxInternal) vertx).removeCloseHook(this);
          }

Would still be nice to learn how can I memoize an arbitrary Future result in vert.x native way (and without using a caching library).
Since the synchronous implementation of memoizer in Guava is under 50 lines I'd expect the asynchronous solution to also be simple.
